# Не отображается маршрут при использовании osmdroid

Tags: android

Пишу небольшое приложение, чтобы построить маршрут движения. Пользуюсь osmdroid. Карта грузится, но не отображается маршрут движения. По логу при движении массив координат получаю

```
private fun initOsm() = with(binding) {
    pl = Polyline()
    pl?.outlinePaint?.color = Color.BLUE
    mapView.controller.setZoom(15.0)
    val notMoving =
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.ic_navigation_stop)
    val moving =
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.ic_navigation_move)
    val mLocProvider = GpsMyLocationProvider(activity)
    val mLocOverlay = MyLocationNewOverlay(mLocProvider, mapView)
    mLocOverlay.enableMyLocation()
    mLocOverlay.enableFollowLocation()
    mLocOverlay.setDirectionArrow(notMoving, moving)
    mLocOverlay.runOnFirstFix {
        mapView.overlays.clear()
        mapView.overlays.add(mLocOverlay)
        mapView.overlays.add(pl)
    }
}
```